# How can i fill an SVG image (on hover) that is inserted into my HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

My HTML has an object referring to an SVG, previously I had saved the svg with a png through inkscape but read it was not possible to edit attributes/properties of my svg image. Currently I am trying to fill the content of my svg outline on hover using css but am not understanding the what's going wrong. The svg image is not filled on the inside, not sure if that makes a difference. Any help would be great thanks. Alternatively I could use jQuery if that has a solution aswell!

HTML:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="/img/corby-outline.svg" id="theSVG">
</object>
```

SVG:

```
 <svg width="212.28mm" height="148.23mm" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 212.28 148.23" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<g transform="translate(-38.28 -36.197)">
    <path id="outlineSvg" d="m39.037 80.913 37.302 92.538 38.169-15.152 9.9761 25.434 30.796-10.282 1.735 4.8704 8.6749-3.7881-1.3012-4.3293 26.025-7.5762-2.6025-7.5762 26.458-9.1997-14.314-36.258 49.88-16.235-2.1687-5.9527-108 38.963-22.121-51.951 16.482-5.9527 10.844-2.7058 90.219-10.282-10.41-18.399-4.7712 4.3293-6.9399 1.0823-6.9399-3.7881z" fill="transparent" stroke="#f00" stroke-width="1.117"/>
</g>
```

CSS:

```
 outlineSvg:hover {
fill: orange;
}

 theSVG:hover {
fill: orange;
 }
```

Comment: It's been a while but I seem to recal you can't do that with an SVG in an `object` tag. I'd have to check.

Comment: Yep...there it is.

Comment: The <svg> element is in a different document and styles don't apply cross-document. You could make the SVG inline or move the hover styles into the SVG document itself.